# Ruby On Rails: Thumbs Up Voting Display Tally Results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, voting, voting-system, vote-up-buttons

I have the Thumbs_Up gem loaded and the voting is working fine.

I added this code to the posts controller:

```
def poll_winners
@posts = Post.tally(
{   :at_least => 1,      
  :limit => 20,
  :order => 'vote_count desc'
})
```

I just can't figure out what to put in the actual view to get it to display.

Is it just `<% poll_winners %>` ?

EDIT2: Here's the complete error message:

```
undefined local variable or method `poll_winners' for #<#<Class:0x000000040a4278>:0x007f55806c3360>
```

**EDIT**Here's my complete posts controller (not sure if it is right):

```
class PostsController < InheritedResources::Base
def vote_up
begin
  current_user.vote_for(@post = Post.find(params[:id]))
  redirect_to [@post]
  flash[:success] = "You have voted successfully"
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  redirect_to [@post]
  flash[:error] =  "You have already voted"
end
end
def poll_winners
  @posts = Post.tally(
{   :at_least => 1,
  :at_most => 10000,
  :limit => 10,
  :order => 'vote_count desc'
})
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just loop through the results of the method `poll_winners`

```
<% poll_winners.each do |pw| %>
  <%= pw %>
<% end %>
```

You can then get a specific attribute of `Post`, for example if it has a `title` you can just do `<%= pw.title %>` instead of just `<%= pw %>` which will return the object.

I am assuming that the method is as follows

```
def poll_winners
  @posts = Post.tally(
    :at_least => 1,      
    :limit => 20,
    :order => 'vote_count desc'
  })
end
```

Comment: Now I'm getting "undefined local variable poll_winners" is this posts controller right? class PostsController < InheritedResources::Base
  def vote_up
    begin
      current_user.vote_for(@post = Post.find(params[:id]))
      redirect_to [@post]
      flash[:success] = "You have voted successfully"
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
      redirect_to [@post]
      flash[:error] =  "You have already voted"
    end
  end
   def poll_winners
      @posts = Post.tally(
  {   :at_least => 1,
      :at_most => 10000,
      :limit => 10,
      :order => 'vote_count desc'
  })
     end
end

Comment: This is the complete message: undefined local variable or method `poll_winners' for #<#<Class:0x000000040a4278>:0x007f55806c3360>

Comment: Please move the `poll_winners` method from the controller to the helper. In the helpers folder you should have a file called `post_helper.rb`.